# Patch objects with RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I believe what I am trying to achieve is similar to an HTTP Patch or deep extend function, but I want to achieve it with rxjs. Say I have the following objects:

```
const arr1 = {
  obj1: { a: 'dog', b: 'cat', c: 'bird' },
  obj2: { a: 'boy', b: 'girl', c: 'guitar' },
  obj3: { a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' }
}

const arr2 = {
  obj1: { a: 'wolf', b: 'lion', c: 'hawk', z: 'bear' },
  obj2: { c: 'car'}
}
```

I then want to use rxjs in order to get the following output:

```
const output = {
  obj1: { a: 'wolf', b: 'lion', c: 'hawk', z: 'bear' },
  obj2: { a: 'boy', b: 'girl', c: 'car' },
  obj3: { a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' }
}
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain your case further? What's the reasoning behind using RxJS here? If all of data pieces are objects and available in one piece at current moment of time, I don't see what it has to do with RxJS. It's just deep merge/extend which comes in a bunch of different flavours (btw they are objects of objects, not arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJS is not for merging Objects, it is [An API for asynchronous programming
with observable streams](http://reactivex.io/)

If you want to merge Objects you can use [Lodash merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.1#merge)

```
var object = {
  'a': [{ 'b': 2 }, { 'd': 4 }]
};

var other = {
  'a': [{ 'c': 3 }, { 'e': 5 }]
};

_.merge(object, other);
// => { 'a': [{ 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, { 'd': 4, 'e': 5 }] }
```

Or the Object spread operator (not officially supported)
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/